# Further Normalization of Standardized data - ANN

Tags: neural-networks, datasets, deep-neural-networks

I want to develop a regression model using the artificial neural network. For developing such a model I use standardised ( z-score normalised ) data.

given below is the sample data set. Here MAX is the real data But I am using MAX-ZS (these values are continues)

[image: Sample Data Set]

So my question is while developing the model do I have to perform further normalization such as Min-Max scaling on my training data?
Any Kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Data scaling or normalization is a process of making model data in a standard format so that the training is improved, accurate, and faster.

So you just have to scale the data once. Doesn't matter what scaler you are using. Just make sure to initialize the scaler with the `training data` and then use the same parameters to scale the `test data`.

The [z-score normalized](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788397872/5/ch05lvl1sec62/scaling-of-data-in-neural-network-models) data (`MAX-ZS`) can be used directly to train the network.